# Problems with PHP login script after hashing database with crypt()

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication, hash

I’m pretty much a complete beginner when it comes to PHP and have been having some problems with my login and redirection script after hashing the database. Keep getting the account not found page coming up when I try to log in and cannot find the problem.

Some background info:

Database name: “user”

Table “users” with columns User ID , Username , Password , Emailaddress , Offer.

Site that I’m working on allows users to complete a number of offers and then get rewarded upon completion. The offer column has the default value of “1” and after an offer is completed it is updated via a script. Upon login the user is redirected according to the value in the offer column. (So on first login user is redirected to example.com/offer1 , after offer 1 is completed this value is updated so on next login user is redirected to offer 2 – in essence storing the users progress)

Anyway , the login was working correctly but was using md5, changed to  crypt() instead and changed the login script but then things went wrong. Now when I try to log in I get directed to the Error , the account cannot be found page. – when I’ve checked in the database and the account is there.  Would be very grateful if some kind person could review my login code and point out where I’m going wrong.

Here’s the script I used to Hash the passwords – I ran this once. Seemed to work as when I looked in DB all passwords appeared to be hashed.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","user");
function Casual($length=22){
    $characters ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $code = "";
    for($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){
        $code = $code.substr($characters,rand(0,strlen($characters)-1),1);
    }
    return $code;
}
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password,Username FROM users");
while($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $newcode= '$2a$07$'.Casual(22).'$';
$hashed_password = crypt($assoc['Password'],$newcode);
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET Password='".$hashed_password."' WHERE Username='".$assoc['Username']."'");
}
?>
```

And here is the login code:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Login to Cash Offers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","user");
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';


  <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checklogin);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1 AND crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
    {
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';      

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

  <h1>Member Login</h1>

  <p>Your just a few seconds away from completing offers! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

  <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above , upon login or if a session is already present, the script looks up the offer value in the database and redirects depending on value. (if default 1 , redirects to example.com/offer 1 ; if 2 then example.com/offer2 etc) I don’t think there’s a problem here as its not even attempting to redirect – just saying user isn’t found. Could it be an issue the hashed passwords aren't being read correctly?

This is the Error.Sorry, your account could not be found.. Bit is going off

Heres’ base.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
$dbname = "user"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
$dbuser = "name"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
$dbpass = "pass"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Here’ s also my registration script

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Register </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

     $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");

     if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
     {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
     }
     else
     {
        $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
        if($registerquery)
        {
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
        }       
     }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Register</h1>

   <p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

    <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly here’s the script which updates the offer value in the table – this one fires after offer 2 is completed and “continue to next offer” is pressed.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","user");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM users      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=2".$plus);
header("location: http://example.com/offer3".$plus);
?>
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You're using `crypt()` in your first body of code, then MD5 for `And here is the login code:` then `if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1 AND crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])` - I can't make heads or tails out of this. If you didn't MD5 "with" `crypt()` to start with, this will fail because of double hashing.

Answer (score 1):

This code is why you get "account not found":

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1 AND crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
 {
    //Good
 }
 else
 {
    //Not found
 }
```

You are only going into the first condition if you found the account *and* the password matches. You have no condition defined for when you find the account, but the password does not match.

To have that work like you seem to want, you'd do something like this:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
 {
    if(crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
    {
        //Good
    }
    else
    {
        //Bad password
    }
 }
 else
 {
    //Not found
 }
```

**That said**; note that it's generally *not* a good idea to indicate why the login has failed like this; you would be telling any potential password cracker that their username does not exist, eliminating much of their work. The standard is to do what you have now, but just give a message like this:

> Username or password is incorrect.

---

Also, I'm worried this still won't work; It looks like you hashed the *already hashed* password; to get matches now, you'd have to MD5, then `crypt`, because that's how you got your current hashes.

Comment: Thanks  @Andrew Barber I think I've made a complete mess of it and the double hashing is the problem. Initially I just used MD5 then someone here suggested using the Crypt script to make everything secure and make the changes to the login. Should I just go back to MD5 even though it is less secure?